# How can I detect browser details in NestJs/NodeJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, device-detection

I am trying to integrate device-detector npm module in my application in order to detect the browser details. For that I am using this module `npm i device-detector-js`

I have integrated as it is code snippet in my code.

Below is my code:

**app.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

@Get()
getHello(@Req() req): string {
  console.log(req.headers);
  return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import DeviceDetector = require("device-detector-js");

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
private readonly deviceDetector = new DeviceDetector();

getHello(): string {
const userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81(Windows; Intel windows 8_8.1_10_11) Safari/537.36"; 
const result = this.deviceDetector.parse(userAgent);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
return 'Hello World!';
 }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Nest] 23300  - 12/04/2022, 1:26:55 pm     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/test, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 23300  - 12/04/2022, 1:26:55 pm     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +4ms
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google 
 Chrome";v="98"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
 dnt: '1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36'
}
```

It's working but not giving correct info as I am using Windows but it's showing Macintosh. Why is this happening?

Comment: It because you are hardcoded your user agent :))) You should grab user agent from request somehow and pass it to `deviceDetector`

Comment: you need to pass the user-agent header of a request. If you just pass the same string containing `Macintosh` it will always give the same result...

Comment: How can I pass it through request can U please explain or show me a little code.

Comment: @Kuzzy I have updated my post can u please look into it

Comment: "device-detector-js" lib saved my day, thanks for you code!

Answer (score 5):

Just pass headers from controller into service, something like this:

```js
// controller
getHello(@Req() req): string {
  console.log(req.headers);
  return this.appService.getHello(req.headers);
}

// service
getHello(headers: {'user-agent': string }): string {
  const userAgent = headers['user-agent']; 
  const result = this.deviceDetector.parse(userAgent);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  return 'Hello World!';
}
```

Comment: Its working fine inside service can we do this inside controller as well.

Comment: Yes, it almost the same, just move all `DeviceDetector` associated code into controller and pass user agent from headers in the same way: `this.deviceDetector.parse(req.headers['user-agent'])`